# Prevent header being split into multiple page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

In SSRS, there is a `KeepTogether` attribute for groups to prevent them split across 2 pages. But is it possible to apply the `KeepTogether` attribute to headers?

I have a group that has 3 rows of headers, in some cases, when rendering the data, if it comes to the end of the page, but still able to fit 1-2 rows, it will print the 1-2 rows at the current page, and split the rest of the rows to the next page like. Thus, the header will be splitted when export to PDF like the image below:

[image]

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Is there contents before this table that makes it push down?  Give us the whole picture.. you couldn't possibly have your header take up that much space..

Comment: @Harry yes it has contents before the screenshot since this is a header of a group instead of table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to see if it works. Make sure your Row Groups window is showing at the bottom (go to the view menu and check grouping if it isn't). Then press the little down arrow at the top right of that bottom pane and enable advanced mode.

Click the groups. They will highlight a pane in your table. Find the one for the header you are having problems with. Now look at the properties pane on the right (you can use the view menu to turn it on if it's not there). There are a few properties to try here. Try experimenting with KeepTogether and KeepWithGroup options.

If that doesn't work out with you then it looks like your only option is going to be the Insert Page Break Before option in the table options menu.